# HWIOAuth Bundle Errors

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to add HWIOAuth to my symfony 3.4 project and everytime I run the command: "composer require hwi/oauth-bundle" I get this error

In FileLoader.php line 168:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service" (in "C:\wamp64\www\piweb\app/config\services.yml"). Looked for namespace "my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service", found ""fr
>     amework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "fos_user", "httplug", "hwi_oauth", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution", "web_server"" in C:\wamp64\www\piweb\app/
>     config\services.yml (which is being imported from "C:\wamp64\www\piweb\app/config\config.yml").

In YamlFileLoader.php line 698:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service" (in "C:\wamp64\www\piweb\app/config\services.yml"). Looked for namespace "my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service", found ""fr
>     amework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "fos_user", "httplug", "hwi_oauth", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution", "web_server"".

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have `php-http/guzzle6-adapter` and `php-http/httplug-bundle` installed, or are you attempting to install them at the same time as `hwi/oauth-bundle` ? Just checking, as it appears that [these are required](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md#a-add-hwioauthbundle-to-your-project) if you're not setting up your own services.

Comment: I installed them seperatly using composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter:^1.1
composer require php-http/httplug-bundle
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle

Comment: Does it make a difference if you comment out the configuration block referenced in the error message before running `composer require hwi/oauth-bundle`?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but when I deleted everything and restarted it worked, but there are other issues now

Comment: That's because you need to set configuration before installing bundle. Setup user providers. If you are using it with FosUserBundle, set it up first. Go and create config given in later steps and it will be good to go. It has been known problem and not resolved yet.